# Fadeout content when it reaches top header

Tags: html, css, menu, fadeout

I am trying to create a gradient png via `-webkit-gradient` to make an illusion that the content is being faded out when it reaches the top header on scroll so that the content doesn't go behind the header.

Here is what I attempted:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://amymhaddad.s3.amazonaws.com/morocco-blue.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  height: 80px;
}
.gradient-png {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  height: 80px;
}
.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
.site-logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 170px;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu gradient-png">
          <img class="hamburger" alt="menu" />
          <div class="site-logo">Logo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Somehow the mask image is not taking effect, I can still see that my content is behind my menu.

I am trying to achieve something like this, where the text below is the content:
[image: fadeout]

Comment: You're not using [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) correctly. It's meant to work in conjuction with a background image on the same element. Maybe, instead, remove that and use something like `background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));`.

Comment: That would result in an apparent white. I tried using transparent but it didn't work.

Comment: You can, of course, change the color to whatever you prefer. The alpha channel is what produces the fade effect you're asking about. You should try it out to get a better idea of what it looks like and then make adjustments to taste. If that still isn't what you're going for, you'll need to provide more detail about the effect you want.

Comment: I have updated my question to include a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. It is a transparent fade out effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mask-image` is meant to work in conjunction with a background image on the same element. I've added that image in the demo below and cleaned up the `mask-image` syntax. (And made minor modifications to clean up the look.) All changes are commented in the CSS with `/*** ***/`.

Update: Changed how background images are set.

References:

- [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)
- [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)
- [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

```css
:root {
  --background-image: url("https://amymhaddad.s3.amazonaws.com/morocco-blue.png"); /*** added ***/
}
body {
  margin:0; /*** optional addition ***/
}
.wrapper {
  background-image: var(--background-image); /*** modified ***/
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  height: 80px;
}
.gradient-png {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(white 75%, transparent); /*** added; non-chrome ***/
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(white 75%, transparent); /*** corrected; chrome ***/
  background-image: var(--background-image); /*** added ***/
  height: 90px; /*** optional modification ***/
}
.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
.site-logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 170px;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu gradient-png">
    <img class="hamburger" alt="menu" />
    <div class="site-logo">Logo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p><p>Example content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the intended behaviour, but it looks like the content is being cut-off sharp. Is there a way to create a fadeout effect like the sample that I posted?

Comment: I noticed that you placed the background image on .gradient-png, which is not really the right approach when there are other pages with different background-images. It'd be great for an approach that works universally.

Comment: @HNG Fixed the mask-image bug. (Chrome still needs `-webkit-`, other's don't.)

Comment: @HNG Adjusted how background images are selected. Setting `--background-image` on `:root` (or on `html` or `body`, whichever works best for you), rather than `background-image`, on each page will be reflected in the header overlay. (Note that this is out of scope for your question. Questions should be focused on one thing and new questions should be submitted separately.)